# "No web browser error" for jupyter notebook outside home directory only

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm a Windows user and my default browser is chrome but i like to use firefox for jupyter notebooks.

When I'm in my home directory, I can easily launch a notebook in firefox with
`jupyter notebook --browser="firefox"`

Likewise i can get the same effect by setting `c.NotebookApp.browser = u'firefox'` in the config file.

However, if I switch to any other directory I get this error:
`[W 16:10:32.063 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.` and no browser will launch.  Also if I comment out the browser option in the config file and try to run just `jupyter notebook` with no options in any other directory it will open, but in chrome.

How can i open through firefox outside of my home directory?